# How to use Startswith in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to use `StartsWith` to print names with the letter that the user gives. But I don't know how to use `StartsWith` in Visual Studio. Visual Studio doesn't recognize it.

```
        ArrayList namen = new ArrayList();
        int kosten = 0;
        string naam;
        Console.Write("voer de namen in: ");
        naam = Console.ReadLine();


        while (naam.Length > 0)
        {
            if (namen.Contains(naam) == false)
            {
                namen.Add(naam);
            }

            Console.Write("Voer de namen in: ");
            naam = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        }

        foreach (string n in namen)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            kosten += 10;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(kosten + " euro");
        Console.WriteLine("voer een letter in: ");
        string letter = Console.ReadLine();
```

This is the code where I want to use the method `StartsWith`.

Comment: Check the examples of [this site](https://www.dotnetperls.com/startswith)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check a name of the `namen` ArrayList StartsWith a letter, you can use the following example:

```
        string letter = Console.ReadLine();
        ArrayList namen = new ArrayList();
        foreach (string name in namen)
        {
            if(name.StartsWith(letter))
            {
                // Yes, the name StartsWith the input letter
                // Do Something
            }
        }
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'Startswith' and no extension method 'Startswith' accepting a first argument of type 'ArrayList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) bijles_taak_werken met arrays C:\Users\e6430S\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\bijles_taak_werken met arrays\bijles_taak_werken met arrays\Program.cs 43 Active

Answer (score 0):

Although Odrai's answer is correct and helpful.

But you have to look for other overloaded `StartsWith` methods too.

Like case sensitive or culture dependant cases. because string comparison depends on these two things too.

[String.StartsWith Method (String, StringComparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx)

[String.StartsWith Method (String, Boolean, CultureInfo)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k0axhx9(v=vs.110).aspx)